# Using re.findall to create a new column in a dataframe without brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe by running re.findall on an existing column

I've tried this:

`file1['ID'] = [re.findall(' [a-zA-Z]+\d+$',i) for i in file1.V6]`

And this:

```
IDs = []
for i in file1.V6:
    IDs.append(re.findall(' [a-zA-Z]+\d+$',i)

file1['ID'] = IDs
```

The pattern extraction is succesful but when I look at the newly created 'ID' column all the values are single element lists like:

`['my_returned_match']`

I want each row of the column to only have the match as a string and not a single element list.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you just have one match, why not use `str.extract`? Why `findall`?

Comment: I recommend using `[]` to access DataFrame columns, instead of the `.` attribute style. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores`.

Comment: I forgot to add: If I were you I would take a solid look at the design of your program. The currently accepted solution is quite poor, so that certainly doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks this works per your suggestion:
`file1['ID'] = file1.V6.str.extract(' ([a-zA-Z]+\d+$)')` I get the naming convention point, but why '[ ]' vs '.' ? In R I generally use '$' so thought that was most similar and less typing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the for loops. you could do

```
file1.V6.str.findall(' [a-zA-Z]+\d+$').transform(''.join)
```

Comment: This is interesting. This works, I know that transform is like a summarize function except the return object is of the same length as the input, but why does the ''.join argument work? I thought that would turn it into one long concatenated string

Comment: @Jamalan `transform` does not behave like a summarizing function. What you are thinking about is `aggregate`. That is a summarizing function. `transform` is a vectorized function to perform a specific task on each element of the vector/series. in this case, `join` all the elements for each list in the series.

Comment: I see, so a roundabout way to convert each list value into a string. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Jamalan yes. or you could also do `df.Species.str.findall('setosa').transform(lambda x: x[0] if x else '')`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
file1['ID'] = file1['ID'].apply(lambda x:x[0])
```

EDIT:

Although this is more than one line, you could do this before adding it to the dataset.

```
def return_correct(found):
    if len(found)>0:
        return found[0]
    return None

IDs.append(return_correct(re.findall(' [a-zA-Z]+\d+$',i)))
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added, not all rows have an existing match so some lists are empty, the above gives me a "IndexError: list index out of range". Also I was wondering if there was anyway to do this in one line rather than post correct

Comment: Is this more what you want? Also, you can replace None with "" or similar if you prefer.

Comment: Yes thank you this works perfectly. I was expecting there was an easier way around this, I'm new to python still, and know R primarily, so I'm learning these syntax differences

Comment: No worries. If I helped, please upvote the answer and mark it as correct :)